# Laravel: Add Multiple Keys/Tokens for a single product

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am working on an e-commerce store and the requirement is, While adding a product User can add multiple keys/tokens for one product. Although we can do it with javascript that user can add/delete multiple keys/tokens. But the problem is the design that client wants to implement.

The attached screenshot is the design that client wants.

[image]

Following operations a user can perform on keys/tokens.

Add - Edit - Delete.

The major concern is while updating a product how we will update the Keys/Tokens in database and on frontend who we will manage/track the ID of database table from Keys/Tokens that we will use to update the Keys/Tokens.

What I have in mind is that I can do it with javascript(add multiple form field on events), form hidden fields(add/remove form hidden fields on add/update/delete ) and save in DB table(Relation with Product).

Keys and Products are stored in separate DB tables. Many keys can relate to single product.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are those key/tokens represent? "a User" means admin/manager of the website, or a customer?

Comment: key/tokens will be a random string. 
Yes a user can be admin or manager.

Comment: I didn't meant to ask what type of data you insert there. in order to help you, I'm trying to understand the context of what you are trying to achieve. What are those tokens/keys? what is the use of it?

Comment: There will be a product form in admin panel. Admin can add/remove/update multiple keys for a single product through a single input field showing on frontend. For add/edit admin will use a single input field, But for already added keys, they will not display in input fields.(Image is attached for required design for already added keys). These unique keys will shared with customers via email. Customer can use the product only once by using that shared token/key.
The problem is how we will manage the data of keys while updating a product.